# Running ffmpeg command on Android results in "Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0'"

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, android

I am using this command for replacing audio of video and genrate new video having new audio. Here file1 is my video.mp4, file2 is my audio.mp3 and output would be the output.mp4:

```
complexCommand = new String[]{"-y", "-i", file1.toString(), "-i", file2.toString(), "-c", "copy", " -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0", rootPath + "/output.mp4"};
```

Below is My code:

```
    private void changeAudioofVideo(String selectedUri, String videoPath) {

    String[] complexCommand;


    File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0");
    if (!f.getParentFile().exists())
        f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    if (!f.exists())
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    file1 = new File(videoPath);
    if (file1.exists()) {
        Log.d("yes", "File 1 exists");
    } else {
        Log.d("no", "File 1 not exists");
    }

    file2 = new File(selectedUri);
    if (file2.exists()) {
        Log.d("yes", "File 1 exists");
    } else {
        Log.d("no", "File 1 not exists");
    }

    String rootPath = f.getPath();

    complexCommand = new String[]{"-y", "-i", file1.toString(), "-i", file2.toString(), "-c", "copy", " -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0", rootPath + "/output.mp4"};

    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);

    try {
        //Load the binary
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Supported by Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {

        final String finalRootPath = rootPath;
        ffmpeg.execute(complexCommand, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.d("Success", message);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful" + finalRootPath.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Uri path = Uri.parse(finalRootPath + "/output.mp4");
                playVideo(path.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.d("progress", message);
                pd.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.d("failure", message);
                pd.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d("Start", "merge started");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d("finish", "merge finish");
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


   }
```

Below is my output:

```
   05-26 18:39:35.533 29188-29188/com.example.codal.videotm D/failure: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-and    roid/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/videokit/out2.mp4':
                                                                  Metadata:
                                                                    major_brand     : isom
                                                                    minor_version   : 512
                                                                    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
                                                                    encoder         : Lavf56.23.100
                                                                    comment         : Courtesy of National Geographic.  Used by Permission.
                                                                  Duration: 00:00:04.20, start: 0.046440, bitrate: 577 kb/s
                                                                    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 160x120 [SAR 9:16 DAR 3:4], 521 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
                                                                    Metadata:
                                                                      handler_name    : VideoHandler
                                                                    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 50 kb/s (default)
                                                                    Metadata:
                                                                      handler_name    : SoundHandler
                                                                [mp3 @ 0xb86ade60] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 132692.
                                                                [mjpeg @ 0xb86c9980] Changing bps to 8
                                                                [mp3 @ 0xb86ade60] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
                                                                Input #1, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/Download/01 Kaari Kaari - Dobaara.mp3':
                                                                  Metadata:
                                                                    album           : Dobaara (SongsMp3.Co)
                                                                    artist          : Arko , Asees Kaur
                                                                    album_artist    : Arko & Asees Kaur
                                                                    composer        : Arko
                                                                    performer       : SongsMp3.Co
                                                                    copyright       : SongsMp3.Co
                                                                    disc            : 1/1
                                                                    encoded_by      : iTunes 12.6.0.100
                                                                    genre           : Bollywood
                                                                    TEXT            : SongsMp3.Co
                                                                    TPE4            : SongsMp3.Co
                                                                    TRSN            : SongsMp3.Co
                                                                    TOPE            : SongsMp3.Co
                                                                    TOLY            : SongsMp3.Co
                                                                    publisher       : SongsMp3.Co
                                                                    title           : Kaari Kaari (SongsMp3.Co)
                                                                    track           : 1/1
                                                                    date            : 2017
                                                                  Duration: 00:03:46.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 324 kb/s
                                                                    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
                                                                    Stream #1:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 600x600 [SAR 96:96 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
                                                                    Metadata:
                                                                      comment         : Cover (front)
                                                                [NULL @ 0xb86cab70] Unable to find a suitable output format for ' -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0'
                                                                 -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0: Invalid argument
05-26 18:39:35.543 29188-29188/com.example.codal.videotm D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
05-26 18:39:35.543 29188-29188/com.example.codal.videotm D/finish: merge finish
```

Comment: If you look into the log, ffmpeg says that its *output* file is: `'ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/videokit/out1.mp4 -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/01 Kaari Kaari - Dobaara.mp3 -codec copy -shortest /storage/emulated/0/output.mp4'` — that's clearly wrong, it should just be `/storage/emulated/0/output.mp4`. Your command is not properly formatted, so there must be an error in the way you are calling ffmpeg from your source code. But you haven't shown us the complete code, or the value of `complexCommand`.

Comment: @slhck Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not consistent in the way you construct your command.

You should split it into individual arguments:

`complexCommand = new String[]{"-y", "-i", file1.toString(), "-i", file2.toString(), "-c", "copy", "-map", "0:v:0", "-map", "1:a:0", rootPath + "/output.mp4"};`

Comment: Just added -shortest before rootPath